Measuring the frequency of a square wave using rising edge interrupt
I am using a Texas Instruments C2000 board. On a GPIO I have attached a rising edge interrupt. A square wave of approximately 50 Hz is fed into this GPIO. This wave is from a comparator which introduces some jitter around the edges of the square wave. To work around this I disable the interrupt for about 15 ms (have varied this value.)
I tested this code on a signal from a signal generator (clean wave, no jitter) and my code works fine. When I use the signal from the comparator, the measured frequency is always around the time I stopped it for. So if 15 ms, then 66 Hz, as if the moment I enable the interrupt it is triggered.
Edit: I'm trying to deal with multiple rapid false edges due to a noisy comparator output basically
My ISR:
__interrupt void Grid_ZCD(void)
{
    // Disable ZCD int

    Interrupt_disable(INT_XINT1);
    Grid_ZCD_Flag = 2; // Grid ZCD flag set

    mytimercount = CPUTimer_getTimerCount(CPUTIMER1_BASE);
    CPUTimer_reloadTimerCounter(CPUTIMER1_BASE);

    Grid_Period = 10000000 - mytimercount;
    myT = 8.3333e-9 * (float) Grid_Period;
    freq = 1 / (float) myT;

    //
    // Acknowledge this interrupt to receive more interrupts from group 1
    //
    Interrupt_clearACKGroup(INTERRUPT_ACK_GROUP1);

}

This piece of code is to enable again it in another ISR:
if (Grid_ZCD_Flag == 1)
{
    blanking_time++;
    if (blanking_time >= stop_cycles)
    {
        blanking_time = 0;
        Grid_ZCD_Flag = 0;     
        // enable ZCD int
        Interrupt_enable(INT_XINT1);
    }
}

Is there a better way to do this or am I making a mistake somewhere?

I don't know anything about that MCU, but usually interrupts have both the Enable bit and a Pending Flag bit. If your edge happens multiple times, you get an interrupt which is already pending for execution and is executed as soon as you enable it.

I don't know the microcontroller, either, but: I'm almost certain that a microcontroller that has a timer unit with features as shown in your code can autonomously reset the counter. Doing this in an ISR is a fundamentally flawed idea, as ISRs have latency.

When you say "jitter", do you mean jitter (i.e: the edge shifts early / late in time, unclear why you'd want to gate the timing system), or do you mean that the comparator produces multiple edges due to low/no hysteresis?

I don't understand why you're disabling the interrupt.  That doesn't feel very robust

On @Attie 's point, do you mean noise, not jitter? So you get multiple edges where you'd only want one edge? I think you don't mean jitter.

@Justme this makes sense , but the disable interrupt function should clear this no ?  This is what the function does : 1. Disable interrupts globally (DINT or SETC INTM).
2. Clear the PIEIER bit for the interrupt.
3. Wait 5 cycles to make sure that any propagating interrupt has reached the CPU IFR register.
4. Clear the CPU IFR bit for the interrupt's PIE group.
5. Clear the PIEACK bit for the interrupt's PIE group.
6. Enable interrupts globally (EINT or CLRC INTM).

@Velvet , i apologize , the 1.5 ms is wrong , its 15 ms

@Attie  yes i'm referring to the comparator producing multiple edges due to low hysteresis

Ok. That’s not jitter then. Might want to edit the question to clarify that you’re instead trying to deal with multiple rapid false edges due to a noisy comparator output. I’d also consider Attie’s advice and try solving this at the comparator itself.

Please post schematics showing the comparator circuit.

@user412839 Like I said, I don't know what your disable interrupt function does, but I would expect that a function that disables interrupts does exactly that, I would not expect it to clear pending interrupts, and plus, you would need to clear the pending interrupts before enabling them.

You're only showing the software side of it, but the source of the problem is in the hardware. Please post the schematic. Only when we understand the problem can a suitable solution be found. Just playing with the software may not solve it reliably. Thanks.

To address your terminology and conceptual approach first... "jitter" is when you have a good / clean edge, but it wanders early / late in the time domain.

From your comments, what you're actually dealing with is multiple edges, which may look like this on an oscilloscope or logic analyser:

The most robust way to address this is in hardware - either by adapting your comparator into a schmitt trigger (i.e: adding hysteresis) or low-pass filtering the signal after the comparator / before the I/O pin (assuming the I/O pin itself has enough hysteresis, this is the less robust option).
A schmitt trigger has a different threshold for rising vs falling edges (the threshold effectively changes away from the current point once it's been reached). In the time domain it would look something like below, where the dashed red line is the rising threshold voltage, and blue is the falling threshold. Once you've crossed the rising threshold, the output changes, and doesn't then change again until you cross the falling threshold. The wider this hysteresis, the better noise immunity you have - however the more misshapen your signal may be, due to missing edges, temporal shift, etc...

This is more commonly plotted as Vin vs. Vout:

The issue you have at present, is that the signal at the comparator has too much noise, and/or the comparator has too little hysteresis. i.e: "your signal is wiggling around, and crossing the rising and falling threshold on what should nominally be a monotonic rise". This can also be problematic for particularly slow signals, where they spend too much time at the threshold point(s). Note, that nothing is perfect, and therefore your input signal will not be free of noise, and the threshold voltage will not be a single fixed point either.

It seems what you're planning to do is disable the interrupt on the first edge, and then re-enable it after some time has passed. This is a viable firmware-only approach to your problem, however there are things you aren't aware of.
Generally speaking:

Interrupts have a "pending flag" and an "enable flag"
The pending flag can be set even when the enable flag is unset
The pending flag is set whenever the event occurs - in the example above, it would be set on each of the four rising edges
The pending flag can generally be cleared by software
The pending flag is AND'ed with the enable flag - the output controls whether the ISR is actually executed or not
Some devices / peripherals require that the ISR explicitly clears the pending flag, while others will do this implicitly on execution of the ISR
If the pending flag is already set when the enable flag is set, the ISR will be executed immediately

You have two options:

Leave the interrupt enabled at all times, and gate the handling of the interrupt from within the ISR - i.e: compare the time since the last interrupt occurred and just ignore it if it's below a threshold
Clear the pending flag immediately before you re-enable the interrupt, to prevent what you're seeing now


As a side note: You're currently doing floating point calculations in the ISR - generally a bad idea in interrupts because it will take a lot longer than integer arithmetic on devices with "soft-float" implementations, and it's generally not deterministic. ISRs should also do the bare minimum where possible - in your case, I'd suggest you just store mytimercount, and perform the calculations elsewhere / on demand.
Additionally, if your timing precision is important, it would be much better to use a timer's dedicated capture input (paired with resolving your comparator's hysteresis)... there is always going to be some non-constant time between the event occuring, and the ISR's execution actually starting - this will depend on many things, and may be significant if higher prioritiy ISRs are executed in parallel.

Thank You for explaining in detail. We have implemented your advice and its working perfectly !

Excellent, well done!

As others noted, it is expected behavior for the interrupt to trigger again if it was disabled and the flag is still set. So you need to clear the interrupt before re-enabling it.
That will not solve your measurement problem though. You either need to fix the comparator hysteresis at the hardware level. Hardware solutions:

Filter the signal at your GPIO with a bypass capacitor to ground (experiment with a few values, 100 nF is a good starting point usually or compute an actual low-pass filter)
Manually set hysteresis if your schematic and component allows it

Firmware solution:
Sample the first and last interrupt times and average them. You would do this by recording the timer values for first and latest interrupt. Latest is overwritten each GPIO interrupt until your grace period (15 ms) is over. Once the grace period is over, you average the timer values and get your period.
The better way is to fix at the hardware level. The firmware fix will be so imprecise it's not worth implementing in my opinion. After all, you're trying to measure something, not write code that will tell you the arbitrary result you expect.

"Filter the signal at your GPIO with a bypass capacitor to ground" (a) Just connecting a capacitor to it really is a bad idea: loading up driving circuit without understanding it, and with try-it-and-see values. That driver may well be the output of the comparator, for instance, and a capacitor on that output would cause problems rather than solve any. (b) An RC filter (not just C) slow enough to remove multiple edges from the driver would output relatively slow rise/fall edges which would increase inaccuracy in their later measurement. Downvoting accordingly, I'm afraid.

Point taken for (a). For (b), it all depends on comparator output pulse width and total bounce time. This approach usually works for buttons. Without seeing the circuit, it is difficult to estimate the added imprecision, and I think it would improve the repeatability of the measurement. You can then measure rise/fall settling time to calibrate the setup and get accurate results.

Were you just taking the switch debouncing idea and applying to (b), then? Switch debounce is very imprecise, just looking for switch eventually ON or eventually OFF. This needs to measure fairly precisely from edge to edge. It's going into a GPIO which have imprecise switching points even if it's a Schmitt input. With a pulse period of typically 20 ms (50 Hz), the filter will make the trip points, and so the measurement, worse. Can I just add that your question recommends trial and error, your comment measurement-trial-error, rather than designing a circuit with calculated values for the job.

(cont'd) The trouble with trial-and-error/try-it-and-see is that it works with the tolerances/characteristics of just that one built circuit, not all those possible. That's unreliable for volume production, even if just making 5 or 10. It also means the problem wasn't fully understand and the best solution found (where best meets the balance of cost, time, application, manufacture and field service requirements). I'm afraid it can't be good engineering. It's best to understand the circuit and software, identify the problem then design it out values calculated for best attainable performance.

"bounce time" ... we don't know, but it's probably not an open-drain / open-collector (or equivalent) - this isn't an issue of physically bouncing contacts, but a signal that is likely driven push-pull.
